# sharing database file

Tags: java, android, file-sharing, android-fileprovider

I am trying to share database file located in

> /data/data/appid/databases/data.db

by fileProvider But I get following error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/
```

my  file_provider_paths.xml is as follow:

```
<paths>
<files-path name=”databases” path=”/” />
</paths>
```